# Fastly rename components in c# - windows forms in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing the table with many buttons and I am tired of manually renaming it by clicking on a button and then on the name and changing it then the same again and again. I have 81 buttons... soo I have at least 162 clicks + writing the name.

[Here is which clicks I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux1U1.png)

Comment: Can't add the Buttons dynamically at runtime?

Comment: And how I can then write functions to it? Manually? Will it work, or is it harder than just writing a function, I mean will it refer to the specific button?

Comment: You hook the button to the handler, using `myButton.SomeEvent += MyEventHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generate the Buttons at runtime and you don't really need a known name. You can use the Tag property and a single event handler for all buttons.

```cs
for (int x=0; x < 81; x++)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = x.ToString(); // Set the text you need
    btn.Tag = x.ToString();  // Set a unique tag
    btn.Click += btOK_Click;

    MyPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
}

private void btOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tag = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();

    switch(Tag)
    {
        case "XXX":
           break;

        case "YYY":
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but I actually don't know what to do with that MyPanel.Add thing, what should I write there or change it, it is underlined red, with mistake.

Comment: MyPanel doesn't exists, I supposed you use a panel to hold all your buttons

Comment: I have a panel there, but I can't write panel1.Add
I just can't add that "Add" it writes it doesn't exist. I mean that the "Add" definition doesn't exist at least VS tells me soo.

Comment: Panel.Controls.Add

Comment: Okey this worked for me with adding location, by some variables. Great advice thx.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot I can assume you named all buttons but1,but2,butn+1.
So you could actually use a `foreach` loop.
Like this:

```
int name = 1;
foreach (Control c in myForm.Controls)
{
  if (c is Button)
  {
    ((Button)c).Name = "but" + Convert.ToString(name++);
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it out, but I figure it will work.
Hope it helps!

Comment: You can rename the button and have the click function named on the new name, even when it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: A neat trick for the casting is `if (c is Button button) { button.Name = ... }` where **button** is a local variable of c cast to Button

Comment: Does the thing in runtime. However, original poster wanted, for whatever reason, to rename buttons and handlers in design time